# Wordpress Debugging Techniques - hide error notices using custom mu-plugin?

Tags: wordpress, debugging, error-handling

I have an old Wordpress site running under PHP 5.4 which is throwing a lot of minor error notices such as undefined index.

I'm not able to fix these - the errors are coming from a bunch of 3rd party plugins on a site that I did not develop and don't have the time to fix.

The quick fix for the moment is to hide the error notices.
Adding this to wp-config.php hides errors from the screen, writing them to the debug.log file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I'd like to decrease the verbosity of the errors in the log file by using something like:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);
```

I read the only way to do this is by creating a custom must-use plugin (mu-plugin).

Is this still the current/best technique to do this (as of Wordpress 4.2.2)?
(without using a 3rd party debug tool).

Does anyone have a sample of this type of plugin for reference? I'm finding it difficult to locate information on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can change on wp-config.php file replace this code .

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

replace with

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', false);
```

now your error message hide.

Comment: hi, i want to hide only error warnings - not actual errors

Comment: I don't want to hide the errors - I want to conotrl which errors levels I see - ie hide the error warning notices but show the serious errors

Comment: i have another two solution for this.
1.)  `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING); `  put this wp-config.php file in wordpress.  **OR**  2.) `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` put this php.ini file

Comment: [http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php](http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)   check this .

Comment: Cool - I'l check it out

Comment: Note that your solutions won't work - I'm trying to log the errors to the Wordpress debg file. The error reporting you mention will not work in my case (as I stated in my Q)